# How to change values in an array in an efficient way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

I am getting the following arrays from external api endpoint.

Input:-

```
1. [["date", "country_name", "month"], ["2019-02-21", "US", "Jan"]]
2. ["name", "homeAddress", "zipcode"]
```

Expected Output:-

```
1. [["Date", "Country Name", "Month"], ["2019-02-21", "US", "Jan"]]
2. ["Name", "Home Address", "Zipcode"]
```

How can I change the each array in an efficient way in Ruby on Rails?

Update:
  Some of the name are different in expected as follows

Input:

```
["column1", "column2", "date"]
```

Expected output:

```
["column3", "column4", "Date"]
```

How can I get the above output?

Answer:-

Inputs:-

```
a=['1', '2', '3', '4']

b= {"1"=>"10", "2"=>"20", "3"=>"30"}
```

Execute:

```
c=a.map{|i| b[i].nil?? i : b[i] }
```

Output:-

```
 ["10", "20", "30", "4"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to replace '_' with space or bring space when capital letter is encountered within string,

Try following rails methods to do so,

```
"now_isTheTime".titleize.camelize
 => "Now Is The Time"
```

Answer (score 0):

```rb
ar1 = [["date", "country_name", "month"], ["2019-02-21", "US", "Jan"]]
ar2 = ["name", "homeAddress", "zipcode"]


def formatter(string)
 return string if string.length < 3 || string.count("0-9").positive?

 string.titleize.camelize
end

ar1.map{ |sub_arr| sub_arr.map(&method(:formatter)) }
ar2.map(&method(:formatter))
```